# Navigatable Grid Lost Focus to Top When Setting Data Item Value

Tags: navigation, grid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with "**navigatable**" and "**scrollable**" options enabled. 
I have a custom template column which includes a checkbox inside. And there are a few records to make vertical scroll visible.

When I set a dataItem value in the "**change**" event of my custom checkbox, the grid changes its focus to the top row of the same column. Which also means; if I click a checkbox at the bottom of the scrolled grid, the scroll goes top of the records. I've discovered the case occurs only when the "navigatable" option is enabled. If I disable it, it does not lose focus.

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mKrhJ/3/) of this case:

```js
function chkChanged() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
    var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    if (!item) {
        return;
    }
    item.fields["CheckBox"].editable = true;
    item.fields["FirstName"].editable = true;
    item.set("CheckBox", isChecked);
    item.set("FirstName", isChecked.toString().toLowerCase());
    item.fields["FirstName"].editable = false;    
    item.fields["CheckBox"].editable = false;    
    setTimeout(reBindChangeEvents, 200);
}


function reBindChangeEvents() {
    $(".chk").unbind("change", chkChanged);   
    $(".chk").change(chkChanged);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: createRandomData(10),
            group: {
                field: "City"
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        CheckBox: {
                            type: "bool",
                            editable: false
                        },
                        FirstName: {
                            type: "string",
                            editable: false
                        },
                        LastName: {
                            type: "string",
                            editable: true
                        },
                        City: {
                            type: "string",
                            editable: false
                        },
                        Title: {
                            type: "string",
                            editable: false
                        },
                        BirthDate: {
                            type: "date",
                            editable: false
                        },
                        Age: {
                            type: "number",
                            editable: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10
        },
        height: 300,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: false,
        editable: true,
        filterable: true,
        groupable: true,
        //navigatable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "CheckBox",
            title: " ",
            template: "<input class='chk' type='checkbox' #= CheckBox && CheckBox.toString().toLowerCase() === 'true' ? checked='checked' : '' # >",
            width: 30,
            filterable: false,
            groupable: false
        }, {
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "First Name",
            width: 150,
        }, {
            field: "LastName",
            title: "Last Name",
            width: 150,
        }, {
            field: "City",
            width: 150,
        }, {
            field: "Title",
            width: 150,
        }, {
            field: "BirthDate",
            width: 500,
            title: "Birth Date",
            template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"MM/dd/yyyy") #'
        }, {
            field: "Age"
        }]
    }).data("kendoGrid");    
    setTimeout(reBindChangeEvents, 200);
});
```

Is this a bug, or I am doing something wrong? At the moment, I could not find any other way to disable the "navigatable" option.

**EDIT 1 :**
With the help of the answers here and using Kendo Grid after a 1-year time, this information may help others who have issues about html refreshing and grid performance.
dataItem.set() function always refreshes the whole grid html *(at least in version 2013_Q2)* **You should use grid.editCell($td) method** to switch into cell editing mode. And then grid.closeCell() after setting dataItem value. This lets grid to refresh only td cell html. And helps a lot about grid performance.

---

Comment: You cannot post jsfiddle links without posting _some_ of the code in the question, which I assume is why the formatting of the link was mangled.  Please post the relevant section of the code you are having problems with, the editor will then allow you to post the link normally.  For reference, the link to the code is here Here is  

http://jsfiddle.net/mKrhJ/3/

See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code for details

Comment: @Chilledrat Oops.. Sorry for that =) I didn't know that there was such a rule. But the error message which appeared when i was trying to add the link, was not clear enough to tell me write the real code. I thought it was mentioning the "BBCode" styling code somehow.. Thanks for re-formatting the topic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*With the help of the answers here and using Kendo Grid after a 1-year time, this information may help others who have issues about html refreshing and grid performance:*

dataItem.set() function always refreshes the whole grid html (at least in version 2013_Q2)

**You should use grid.editCell($td)** method to switch into cell editing mode. And then grid.closeCell() after setting dataItem value. This lets grid to refresh only td cell html. And helps a lot about grid performance.

Answer (score 1):

After stepping through the code, I'd say this is a bug in kendoGrid's `refresh` method. If `navigatable` is true, the grid changes its current element to the first grid cell when refreshing the grid widget, scrolls to it and focuses the table again.

Additionally, in Chrome, the `focusTable` function breaks the jsfiddle page for me by moving the top menu bar out of view. It seems to be caused by `table[0].focus()`in the grid's focusTable function, which is called after refreshing the grid. I've seen this behavior before, so I don't think it's an issue with jsfiddle. In fact, calling `$(grid.table).focus();` seems to reproduce the behavior consistently for Chrome.

Edit:

The second bug appears to be fixed in their Q3 release (2013.3.1119).

Comment: I don't know about the second bug you mention, but it is good for now to hear that the first issue is a bug from the component itself. There is new released Q3 version. I will check if the bug remains in the new release. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurred when we try to do the `dataItem.set('IsSelected', checked);`
because re rendered the grid when we did the `dataItem.set('IsSelected', checked);`